# PHPWORD y Pase de variables

Tags: php, phpword

Estoy tratando de realizar unos reportes en Word - usando Php y consultas de Mysql- a través de la librería PHPWORD

Para ellos utilizo dos paginas la 1ra, climalaboralindividual.php

consiste en consultas de la base de datos e impresion en pantalla de los resultados

```
<form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="id" placeholder=" 1ro Ingresa el Nº de Documento"><br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="2do Buscar Candidato">
    </form>


$query = "SELECT * FROM data_usuario WHERE Documento_Usuario = '$id' ";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

y muestras de las mismas mediante

```
<?php  
        while ($rowE = mysqli_fetch_array($query_runE)) 
        {
            ?>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <br>
                <br>
                <h2>Datos del Evaluador</h2>
            <input type="text" class="usuario" name="Nombre_Evaluador" value="<?php echo $rowE['Nombre_Evaluador'] ?> "/>
            <input type="text" class="usuario" name="Test_Asignado" value="<?php echo $rowE['Test_Asignado'] ?> "/>
            <input type="text" class="usuario" name="Motivo_Examen" value="<?php echo $rowE['Motivo_Examen'] ?> "/>

            </form>


            <?php  
        }
            ?>
```

[image: 1r PHP]

En la 2da Hoja, GenerarDocx.php

Genera un documento word, y quiero incluir la información de las consultas de la 1era Hoja

sin embargo, aquí el problema, es como recolecto las variables de la consulta anteriormente mencionada Hoja 1 y las envió a la hoja 2 para generar el reporte en word, o para ser especifico como debería capturar las variables de la 1ra hoja para ser usadas en la 2da, que OPCIONES puedo usar.

Que métodos me podrían sugerir, acordes al código mostrado.

```html
<?php

require_once '../ClimaLaboral/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter;


// Creating the new document...
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

/* Note: any element you append to a document must reside inside of a Section. */

// Adding an empty Section to the document...
$section = $phpWord->addSection();

// Adding Text element to the Section having font styled by default...

$section->addText('REPORTE INDIVIDUAL EVALUACION 
CLIMA ORGANIZACIONAL');
$section->addText('Nombre');
$section->addText('Nombre');
$section->addText('Edad');
$section->addText('Instruccion');
$section->addText('Motivo del examen');
$section->addText('Examinador');
$section->addText('Fecha');


$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addText('Que es clima organizacional?');
$section->addText('El ser humano es esencialmente un ser social y un ser organizado. Ser social significa que el hombre, por su misma naturaleza, tiende a establecer relacio- nes de cooperación e interdependencia permanentes para el logro de sus propósitos.');
$section->addText('El ser humano es esencialmente un ser social y un ser organizado. Ser social significa que el hombre, por su misma naturaleza, tiende a establecer relacio- nes de cooperación e interdependencia permanentes para el logro de sus propósitos.');
$section->addText('El ser humano es esencialmente un ser social y un ser organizado. Ser social significa que el hombre, por su misma naturaleza, tiende a establecer relacio- nes de cooperación e interdependencia permanentes para el logro de sus propósitos.');
$section->addText('Dimensiones del clima organizacional?');

$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addText('1. Estructura: representa la percepción que tienen los miembros de la organización acerca de la cantidad de reglas, procedimientos, trámites y otras limitaciones a que se ven enfrentados en el desarrollo de su trabajo. La medida en que la organización pone el énfasis en la burocracia, versus el énfasis puesto en un ambiente de trabajo libre, informal e inestructurado.');
$section->addText('2. Responsabilidad: es el sentimiento de los miembros de la organización acerca de su autonomía en la toma de decisiones relacionadas a su trabajo. Es la medida en que la supervisión que reciben es de tipo general y no estrecha, es decir, el sentimiento de ser su propio jefe y no tener doble chequeo en el trabajo');
$section->addText('3. Recompensa: corresponde a la percepción de los miembros sobre la adecuación de la recompensa recibida por el trabajo bien hecho. Es la medida en que la organización utiliza más el premio que el castigo.');
$section->addText('4. Desafío: corresponde al sentimiento que tiene los miembros de la organización acerca de los desafíos que le impone el trabajo. La medida en que la organización promueve la aceptación de riesgos calculados a fin de lograr los objetivos propuestos.');
$section->addText('5. Relaciones: es la percepción por parte de los miembros de la empresa acerca de la existencia de un ambiente de trabajo grato y de buenas relaciones sociales tanto entre pares como entre jefes y subordinados.');
$section->addText('6. Cooperación: es el sentimiento de los miembros de la empresa sobre la existencia de un espíritu de ayuda de parte de los directivos y de otros empleados del grupo. Enfasis puesto en el apoyo mutuo, tanto de niveles superiores como inferiores.');
$section->addText('7. Estándares: es la percepción de los miembros acerca del énfasis que pone la organización sobre las normas de rendimiento.');
$section->addText('8. Conflictos: es el sentimiento de los miembros de la organización, tanto pares como superiores, aceptan las opiniones discrepantes y no temen enfrentar y solucionar los problemas tan pronto surjan.');
$section->addText('9. Identidad: es el sentimiento de pertenencia a la organización y que se es un elemento importante y valioso dentro del grupo de trabajo. En general, la sensación de compartir los objetivos personales con los de la organización.');

$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addText('Resultados');
$section->addText('A continuación los resultados individuales de la percepción y sentimientos asociados a la  estructura y condición de la organización.');

$categories = array('Estructura','Responsabilidad','Recompensa','Desafío','Relaciones', 'Cooperación', 'Estándares', 'Conflictos', 'Identidad');
$series = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

$chart = $section->addChart('bar', $categories, $series);
$chart->getStyle()->setWidth(Converter::inchToEmu(6.5))->setHeight(Converter::inchToEmu(4));

// Saving the document as OOXML file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');

?>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Dónde está el código que usas para escribir en Word? Sería cuestión de crear una variable con tu código PHP y pasarlo a Word.

Comment: Ya lo agrego, no lo crei necesario. mil disculpas

Comment: Como te decía, en el código PHP donde lees los datos obtenidos, puedes concatenar todo en una variable (formulario incluido), y luego agregarlo como una sección del documento. Supongamos que concatenaste todo correctamente en una variable de PHP llamada `$htmlData`, haces algo como esto:  `$sectionForm = $phpWord->addSection();` Y luego `\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($sectionForm, $htmlData, false, false);` Puedes ver un [ejemplo completo en Github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/samples/Sample_26_Html.php).

Comment: Mi duda como tal radica en, como almaceno y-o envio las variables de la Hoja 1 a la hoja 2 para obviamente integrarla al php que genera el documento.

Comment: Hay muchas formas de hacer eso. ¿La hoja que obtiene los datos de la base de datos espera datos de la hoja que genera el Word para trabajar? Si es así, deberías usar Ajax. En cambio, si son archivos independendientes, puedes hacer un `include`, que sería que adjuntar el contenido del archivo en esa parte donde haces el include. Una vez hecho el include, puedes usar las variables y datos que hay en ese archivo que has incluido.

Comment: Intente con un Include, sesion y Post, sin embargo, por alguna razon no me deja usar las variables, es como si estuviesen vacias aunque me genere la consulta en la 1ra hoja.

Comment: El problema que tienes no queda claro en la pregunta. Lo que se interpreta es que no sabes cómo poner HTML en un correo, pero el problema es más de organización de tus archivos. ¿El formulario que muestras en la imagen es el que quieres enviar? Si es así, ¿por qué no pones en ese archivo el código que envía el email? Así creas tu código de envío de email, le agregas el contenido del formulario y lo envías. Sugiero esto de momento, hasta que aprendas mejor a organizar tus archivos y la lógica del programa mediante el uso de `clases` y demás.

Comment: a ver, tengo 2 .php . En el 1 es el de la imagen, que realiza la consulta segun la informacion introducida en el textbox, en el 2do boton realiza la consulta e imprime los datos en pantalla. en el 3er boton llama al 2do php  generar documento en el quiero usar la informacion del 1ro en forma de variables, para introducirla en la impresion de un documento WORD

Comment: Como ya dije la mejor forma de traer **información dinámica** de un archivo a otro es por medio de Ajax. El archivo 1 (el que el usuario tiene en su pantalla) recoge datos si fuera necesario y los envía a un archivo 2 que está en el servidor. Ese archivo2 recibe los datos, hace la consulta o lo que sea y devuelve el resultado al archivo1 el cual los muestra en pantalla y/o los manda por email o lo que sea. En todo eso no hay recarga de página ni nada, todo ocurre de forma transparente para el usuario. Así es como funciona Ajax.

Comment: No, hermano, no nos estamos entendiendo, pero igual gracias.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y explica mejor las cosas si quieres que te ayudemos. Lo que se interpreta es que no sabes cómo poner el formulario en el email, cuando lo que tienes es un lío sobre el funcionamiento de las cosas. Este tipo de contextos funcionan justo como te lo estoy explicando. Si lo entiendes al revés lo que harás será un código espagueti en tu aplicación.

Comment: Hermano, tengo un lio, nada de lo que he intentado me ha funcionado, por eso he preguntado aca. mira <?php echo $rowE['Nombre_Evaluador'] ?> esta es la que imprime 1 de las informaciones en la pantalla, como, puedo usar esta $rowE['Nombre_Evaluador'] en el 2do archivo. eso es todo, ya intente post, session e include, quizas por el estres lo he hecho todo mal y no lo dudo, quizas sea una tonteria pero no encuentro la forma.

Comment: En la pregunta explica cómo tienes organizado el código. A partir de ahí te diremos la mejor forma de hacerlo. Se trata de que digas simplemente: Tego este archivo con el que hago esto, luego tengo que hacer esto y luego lo otro. En un párrafo se explica tu contexto, no es tan complicado, pero se requiere claridad para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Si el problema es de entendimiento, quizas yo no me se explicar pero tengo el texto ordenado paso por paso desde el 1er php al 2do php. no se que mas debo colocar

Comment: A ver, dices que tienes una primera página con un formulario, la cual usas para hacer una consulta en la base de datos... Esa consulta trae datos y esos son los datos que quieres usar para luego enviarlos por email. ¿Es correcto hasta ahí?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89210/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-julio-manuel-gonzalez-bencomo).